# AWS SNS Push notification not delivered to device though its displaying delivered in cloudwatch

Tags: php, android, amazon-web-services, push-notification, amazon-sns

AWS SNS Push notification is not working for android `GCM` in my application though same code is working pretty good for IOS. I put `cloudwatch` to track down the error but it displaying status as `delivered` in logs but no push notification received in Device.

**Relevant code of application**

```
$platform = 1;
$token = 'user-device-token';
$gcmPlatformArn = 'AWS_GCM_ARN';
$ApnsPlatformArn = 'AWS_IOS_ARN';
$message = 'welcome';

$sns = SnsClient::factory([
    'region'  => 'my-region',
    'version' => 'latest',
    'credentials' => [
        'key' => 'my-key',
        'secret' => 'my-secret'
    ]
]);
if ($platform == 1) { //For Android
    $endPointArn = $sns->createPlatformEndpoint([
    'PlatformApplicationArn' => $gcmPlatformArn,
    'Token' => $token
    ]);
} else {
    $endPointArn = $sns->createPlatformEndpoint([
        'PlatformApplicationArn' => $ApnsPlatformArn,
        'Token' => $token
    ]);
}
$endPoint = $endPointArn['EndpointArn'];

return $sns->publish(['Message' => $message,
              'TargetArn' => $endPoint]);
```

Comment: you don't need to create a new endpoint every time, you should store the endpoint for future use instead of incurring the additional API call.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/mobile-platform-endpoint.html

Comment: I understand that and I am maintaining the endpoint , this is just I only want to share the relevant code causing problem obviously new endpoint is not an issue here as I am not getting push notification for a fresh device